# open new Document with VSTO Add-In - DocumentOpened not firing

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I have an Add-in for Microsoft Visio which is supposed to close the active document and open another document in the same application instead.
Both are working without any problems, but the `DocumentOpened` handler doesn't recognize the opening of the new file (which works perfectly well by opening the file manually).

Code:

```
Visio.Application Vis = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Visio.Document Doc = Vis.ActiveDocument;
Visio.Document new_Doc;

Doc.Save();
Doc.Close();

new_Doc = Vis.Documents.Open(new_filename);
```

Does anyone know why the Add-In does not catch the event and how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let me know if my answer sorted you out. I think you were after executing code when a document is opened. Is that correct?

Comment: @aduguid thanks for the help. Sadly your solution isn't firing either. What do you mean with "after executing code"? 
As a workaround I tried calling an executable with document name as parameter, with the only purpose to open the new document. Then the event handler fires!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. You should be able to fire off your code from `e_Application_DocumentOpened`.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    public static Visio.Application e_application;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application = this.Application;
        e_application.DocumentOpened += new Visio.EApplication_DocumentOpenedEventHandler(e_Application_DocumentOpened);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application.DocumentOpened -= new Visio.EApplication_DocumentOpenedEventHandler(e_Application_DocumentOpened);
        e_application = null;
    }

    private void e_Application_DocumentOpened(Visio.IVDocument doc)
    {
        //whatever you need to do for this event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.OpenEx(<yourFilePath>, (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRW);
```

from:
[microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.openex)